# ¿Como detectar si un objeto $error de formularios de AngularJs esta vacio?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Necesito desactivar un botton con `ng-disabled` si existe cualquier error en un formulario.

```
form(name="myForm", action="", method="post", novalidate)

input(type="submit", value="Register" ng-disabled="//I need to get true here")
```

He intentado cosas como `ng-disabled=myform.$error` pero el `boton` se desactiva aun si no existen errores en el `form`, tienen idea de como puedo lograr eso?

Answer (score 1):

Mediante la clase [Invalid](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form) , haciendo uso como mencionaste de [ngDisabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled), Por ejemplo :

```js
var valida = angular.module('validacion', []);

  valida.controller('main', function($scope) {
    
    $scope.submitForm = function() {

      if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
        alert('Formulario Correcto');
      }

    };

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="validacion" ng-controller="main">

    <form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.usuario.$invalid && !userForm.usuario.$pristine }">
            <label>Usuario</label>
            <input type="text" name="usuario" class="form-control" ng-model="user.usuario" ng-minlength="3" required>
            <span ng-show="userForm.usuario.$error.required"></span>
            <p ng-show="userForm.usuario.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Nombre de Usuario muy Corto.</p>
        </div>
        
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Enviar</button>
        
    </form>
</div>
```